# Updating to a new password not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords

updating password to a new password is not working. cant figure out why. In my controller i have added the code to update the password.

#### My Controller

```
public changePassword(){
  $pass=$this->input->post('oldpassword');
  $npass=$this->input->post('newpassword');
  $rpass=$this->input->post('rnewpassword');
                
  if($this->input->post('submit') != '')
  {
    if($npass!=$rpass){
      return "false";
    }
    else{
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('user');
      $this->db->where('user_name',$this->session->userdata('username'));
      $this->db->where('pwd',md5($pass));
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if($query->num_rows()==1){
        $data = array(
          'pwd' => md5($npass)
        );
        $this->db->where('user_name', $this->username);
        $this->db->update('user', $data); 
        return "true";
      }else{
        return "false";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In view i have added 3 textboxes to get user input and pass it to controller.

#### My View

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ."DashBoardController/changePassword"?>">                 
  <p><label> Old Password </label></p>
  <p><input type="password" id="oldpassword" name="oldpassword"></input></p>
  <p><label>New Password</label></p>
  <p><input type="password" id="newpassword" name="newpassword"></input></p>
  <p><label>Confirm New Password</label></p>
  <p><input type="password" id="rnewpassword" name="rnewpassword"></input></p>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></input>
  <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: `return false;` WITHOUT quotes because way you are making, it returns string - in other hand it always returns true. `FALSE` is boolean value but `"FALSE"` is string that is true by default.

Comment: There is no input with the name submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Pimary Key is a better way

```
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->userid);
        $this->db->update('user', $data);
```